# Is it possible to fill a GridView from the bottom to top, instead of from the top to bottom?

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have a pretty simple question and I could not really find an answer to it on the internet. Basically, I want to fill my ASP.net GridView from the bottom to the top instead of from the top to bottom. I maybe could explain it better with images.

This is what I have now:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

Comment: Sort the source data descending.

Comment: @VDWWD, thanks for the answer. Do you mean the sort the query that the data is coming from? Or is it a GridView propertie?

Comment: No it is not a GridView propery. Best to sort the SQL query, or if it is a DataTable or List<T> sort that descending. That would be easiest.

Comment: @VDWWD, Damn, it was so easy, yet so difficult. Thanks for the help.